# Bulkify the code?

Tags: apex, soql, performance, bulkification

I want to clone the Opportunity record if some conditions satisfied in Opportunity car set which is in related list.

Opportunity (Master)--->Opportunity car set(Child)

My below code is working fine.But am inserting the cloned record inside the for loop.How to bulkify it ?

```
Code

Opportunity newoppCopy;
Opportunity opp = [SELECT Name, Account.name, sample_Total_TTC_amount__c  FROM Opportunity where id = : oppid
];
newoppCopy = opp.clone(false, true);
newoppCopy.Name=opp.Name + ' Clonée ';

List < Opportunity_car_set__c > lstOppCarset=[SELECT Name,Model__r.IsActive,Version__r.IsActive  FROM Opportunity_car_set__c where Opportunity__c = : opp.id];
for (Opportunity_car_set__c oppCarSetActive: lstOppCarset) {
    string activeModel= oppCarSetActive.Model__r.IsActive;
    string activeVersion=oppCarSetActive.Version__r.IsActive;
    if(activeModel==true && activeVersion==true) {
        insert newoppCopy;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Apex Best Practices : https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. Instead of directly inserting the opportunity. Add them to a list and insert the list after the for loop.

```
List<Opportunity> newOppList = new List<Opportunity>();

List < Opportunity_car_set__c > lstOppCarset=[SELECT Name,Model__r.IsActive,Version__r.IsActive  FROM Opportunity_car_set__c where Opportunity__c = : opp.id];
for (Opportunity_car_set__c oppCarSetActive: lstOppCarset) {
    string activeModel= oppCarSetActive.Model__r.IsActive;
    string activeVersion=oppCarSetActive.Version__r.IsActive;
    if(activeModel==true && activeVersion==true) {
        newOppList.add(newoppCopy);        
    }

}

insert newOppList;
```